# IBM FileNet set limt to upload file

Tags: filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator

I want to set size limit to upload document in filenet ,example(set limit size 20MB if user upload file with size 30MB the system validate and don't upload the file

Answer (score 1):

You may code a Event Action Handler, and subscribe it to run synchronous on create/checkin events.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/subscription_procedures.htm#subscription_procedures__creating_eventhandler